# How to use Python to create a matrix without using numpy

Tags: python

I am trying to create a matrix function: def create_matrix(*NumList, rows, cols).

```
def create_matrix(*NumList, rows, cols):
    Fmat = []
    if len(NumList) == rows*cols:
        for i in range(rows):
            Imat = []
            for j in range(cols):
                Imat.append(NumList[rows * i + j])
            Fmat.append(Imat)
        return Fmat
    else: 
        print("The number of elememnts does not match the shape of the matrix.")
```

For create_matrix(*range(4, 19), rows=3, cols=5), the desired output should be:

`[[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]`.

However, I could only generate the following results.  Any solutions to this, thanks!

`[[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]`

Comment: I think it should be `Imat.append(NumList[cols * i + j])`

Comment: Well, you could always use Pytorch tensors...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to pass the number of rows or columns or even modify in the function itself. Or even ask the number of columns & rows with input() function.

```
def workingWithMatrix(m ,n):
#m: number of rows
# n: number of columns

mat = []

for i in range(0,n):
    mat.append([])
for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        mat[i].append(j)
        mat[i][j] = 0
for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        print('Value in row: ', i+1, 'column: ', j+1)
        mat[i][j] = int(input())
print(mat)
```

This function allows the user to introduce the values of every item in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change and it works fine. Instead of `rows * i + j` put `cols * i + j`:

```
Imat.append(NumList[cols * i + j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change in your code:

```
def create_matrix(*NumList, rows, cols):
    Fmat = []

    if len(NumList) == rows*cols:
        for i in range(rows):
            Imat = []
            for j in range(cols):
                Imat.append(NumList[cols * i + j])
            Fmat.append(Imat)
        return Fmat
    else: 
        print("The number of elememnts does not match the shape of the matrix")

n_l= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]        

print(create_matrix(*n_l, rows= 3, cols=5))
print(create_matrix(*n_l, rows= 5, cols=3))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses list comprehension

```
def create_matrix(*NumList, rows, cols):
    matrix = []
    if len(NumList) == rows * cols:
        for x in range(rows):
            matrix.append(list(NumList[x * cols:(x+1)*cols]))
        return matrix
    else:
        print("The number of elememnts does not match the shape of the matrix.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(create_matrix(*range(4, 19), rows=3, cols=5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension and write it like this:

```
def create_matrix(*values,rows,cols):
    return [  [*values[r:r+cols]] for r in range(0,rows*cols,cols) ]
```

A generalization of this approach would allow you to create matrices of any number of dimensions:

```
def matrix(dims,*values):
    if len(dims) == 1: return list(values)
    block = 1
    for d in dims[1:]: block *= d
    return [ matrix(dims[1:],*values[r:r+block]) for r in range(0,dims[0]*block,block)]

m = matrix((3,2,3),*range(4, 22))
print(m)
# [[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]], [[16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]]]
```